# How to parse a flattened Json?

Tags: java, json

**I have a requirement to use flattened structure JSON, for example below hierarchical Json:**

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "employee1": {
        "employeeId": 123,
        "name": "ABC",
        "type": "permanent",
        "address": {
          "street": "",
          "city": "",
          "zipcode": 123456
        },
        "phoneNumbers": [
          123456,
          987654
        ],
        "designation": "Manager",
        "properties": {
          "age": "29 years",
          "joiningDate": "17-may-2017",
          "salary": "1000 USD"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "employee2": {
        "employeeId": 123,
        "name": "XYZ",
        "type": "parttime",
        "address": {
          "street": "",
          "city": "",
          "zipcode": 345645
        },
        "phoneNumbers": [
          345332,
          675444
        ],
        "designation": "Contractor",
        "properties": {
          "age": "35 years",
          "joiningatDate": "17-june-2015",
          "salary": "700 USD"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
**Could be represented as flat structure Json as below(generated this using json-flattener):**
```

---

```
{
  "employees[0].employee1.address.zipcode": 123456,
  "employees[0].employee1.address.city": "",
  "employees[0].employee1.address.street": "",
  "employees[0].employee1.name": "ABC",
  "employees[0].employee1.employeeId": 123,
  "employees[0].employee1.designation": "Manager",
  "employees[0].employee1.type": "permanent",
  "employees[0].employee1.phoneNumbers[0]": 123456,
  "employees[0].employee1.phoneNumbers[1]": 987654,
  "employees[0].employee1.properties.joiningDate": "17-may-2017",
  "employees[0].employee1.properties.salary": "1000 USD",
  "employees[0].employee1.properties.age": "29 years",
  "employees[1].employee2.address.zipcode": 345645,
  "employees[1].employee2.address.city": "",
  "employees[1].employee2.address.street": "",
  "employees[1].employee2.name": "XYZ",
  "employees[1].employee2.employeeId": 123,
  "employees[1].employee2.designation": "Contractor",
  "employees[1].employee2.type": "parttime",
  "employees[1].employee2.phoneNumbers[0]": 345332,
  "employees[1].employee2.phoneNumbers[1]": 675444,
  "employees[1].employee2.properties.joiningDate": "17-june-2015",
  "employees[1].employee2.properties.salary": "700 USD",
  "employees[1].employee2.properties.age": "35 years"
}
```

My problem is if my service receives flattened Json like above, how to convert it to java domain objects automatically like:

```
class Employee{
Address address;
Properties property;
}
```

Does any Java Json parser supports this automatic conversion or i will have to implement own parsing logic splitting the keys based on dot in the keys?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The format you proposed below, is the exact same thing as the one above, it's just a matter of how you express the nesting.

Comment: Thanks LppEdd, my problem is how to parse second Json in java & convert to objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [json-flattener](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener).

It does what you want, and even more.

The usage is simple as this:

```
String json = "{ \"a\" : { \"b\" : 1, \"c\": null, \"d\": [false, true] }, \"e\": \"f\", \"g\":2.3 }";
String jsonStr = JsonFlattener.flatten(json);
System.out.println(jsonStr);
// Output: {"a.b":1,"a.c":null,"a.d[0]":false,"a.d[1]":true,"e":"f","g":2.3}
```

Comment: I generated flat structure Json using json-flattener. My problem is to parse this flat structure Json in java & populate Java domain objects as mentioned in problem statement. One possible solution could be to unflatten the Json using json-flattener, but was looking if there is a way to parse flattened Json directly.

Comment: You can unflatten your json with json-flattener as well. And then convert it to Java object using Gson or Jackson, or whatever converting tool you can find.